# Русский язык в .dox файлах (doxygen)

Tags: кодировка, документация, doxygen

Ситуация следующая:
Сгенерировал документацию с помощью doxygen. В dconfig прописал в поле `INPUT_ENCODING` кодировку `cp1251` для поддержки кириллических комментариев в коде.
Начал делать титульную страницу для документации - создал файл .dox и в нём после тега `\mainpage` создал страничку с использованием кириллицы. Но после генерации вместо кириллицы там мусор. При этом комментарии кириллицей в исходных файлах отображаются адекватно.

Пробовал менять кодировку самого .dox файла на `cp1251`, не помогло.

Что делать?

Comment: пиши всё в utf8

Comment: тогда кириллические комменты в исходных файлах ломаются(
ваще можно в dconfig прописать, чтобы файлы с расширением .dox были в UTF-8, а все остальное в cp1251, но это как-то костыльно по-моему

Comment: переведи исходники в utf8 c bom